# Can not destroy session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I want to destroy session data but can not do that.

When I Click on Logout Button it always show Some Problem has been occured, Value of var_dump() shows NULL.

Display an error such as Message: **session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session**

Controller: **Users.php**

```
class Users extends CI_Controller
{

    public function logout()
    {
        $result = $this->session->sess_destroy();
        var_dump($result = $this->session->sess_destroy());
        if($result)
        {
            echo "You are logged Out!!";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Some problem has been occured";
        }
    }

public function login()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer-id', 'custid', 'trim|required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
        {
            echo "Please Enter Customer ID";
        }
        else
        {


            $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'password', 'trim|required');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
            {
                echo "Please Enter Password";
            }
            else
            {
                $custid = $this->input->post("customer-id");
                $password = $this->__encrip_password($this->input->post('pass'));

                if('loginuser' == TRUE)
                {


                    $data = $this->user_model->get_username($custid);
                    //$data['custid'] = $custid;
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('data',$data);
                    $this->session->keep_flashdata('data');
                    var_dump($this->session->flashdata('data'));
                    //echo $data;
                    redirect('users/clientview');
                    //$this->load->view('clientview', $data);

                }
                else
                {
                    $result = $this->user_model->login($custid, $password);
                    if ($result) 
                    {

                        $sessiondata = array('customer-id' => $custid, 
                                'loginuser' => TRUE);

                        $this->session->set_userdata($sessiondata);
                        $data['custid'] = $custid;
                        echo "You have successfully logged-in :)";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo $custid;
                        echo $password;
                        echo "Invalid Username or Password";
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need session_start(); before you can destroy it

also header("Location ...) is sending out headers so you can't close the session afterwards. do the redirect after closing the session

Comment: @Raj See tag codeigniter

Comment: Why do you assume a problem has occurred? I don't know what `sess_destroy()` is supposed to return, but the manual does not mention any return value so I would not test for that or rely on it. Note that the php warning is probably caused by the fact that you call the method twice.

Comment: Debug it this way: `public function logout(){$this->session->sess_destroy();var_dump($this->session->userdata());}`

Comment: It is showing array(0) { }. Is that mean the session data has been cleared?

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to destroy the session TWICE.

```
$result = $this->session->sess_destroy();
var_dump($result = $this->session->sess_destroy());
```

Do this instead as the first line destroys the session, the second will throw that error about an uninitialized session because you attempt to destroy it for a second time in the second line.

```
$result = $this->session->sess_destroy();
var_dump($result);
```

> I am also not sure if `sess_destroy()` actually returns anything for you to test?

Comment: I would guess that the second time with the `var_dump()` was introduced to debug the problem. So I think the real problem is that the OP is testing the return value of `sess_destroy()` which does not exist or is at least undocmented as far as I can see.

Comment: @jeroen I think you are probably right, but my codeigniter is a bit rusty.

Comment: Yea I had to as well, seems unlikely as what would be the point of returning anything. What would you do with a failed to do it status anyway

Comment: Ok. The first problem has been solved and i got it why it was occuring. but i can't solve the other one. session data is not being destroyed.

Comment: What are you looking at that makes you think that the session has not been destroyed?

Comment: Bcoz when i call function logout, it is showing the else condition when therre is some error. Another thing is that after logging out when i press back in browser, I am able to go to the page with the username and id.